# Is it "house for rent" OR "house to rent" OR are both the same?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, idiomatic-language

If you are looking for a house online, should you type in the search box **"house to rent"** or **"house for rent"**?

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: What country are you writing for? Americans, Brits, Australians, Indians, etc., will answer this question differently.

Comment: A focus on generality makes this more widely useful.

Comment: @fertilizerspike - indeed.

Comment: I'd say there is no difference, both are fully understandable, and both mean a house that can be rented.

Comment: The Brits say House to Let, rent. AmE speakers use House for Rent. You might see a sign in front of a house that says House to Let or House for Rent. I doubt you'd see House to Rent.,

Comment: Also, the meaning for either could depend on whether you are using "to rent"  in the sense of providing the house or the sense of obtaining use of the house.

Comment: I would say that the phrase "house to rent" would slightly more likely be used by someone *looking for a house* (e.g. in an advertisement), while "house for rent" would slightly more likely be used by someone *offering a house for rent*.

Comment: When you enter a phrase in a search box, it is usually not very important what students or native speakers of English think of your wording. What is important is how the search engine interprets your wording, which is an entirely different concern. It might be that typing "house rent rental" (which is bad English) would have just as good or better results in the search engine than either of the two idiomatically correct English phrases.

Answer (score 5):

They're interchangeable, but one version might be preferable over another in an area, and each *could* be interpreted *slightly* differently:

- "I'm looking for a house **to** rent," implies that I want to rent it. I.E., I have the *intention* of renting it.
- "I'm looking for a house **for** rent," implies that I'm searching for a house that *has been put up for* rent. I.E., though it's possible I want to rent it myself, it *could* be for my son.

That said, the difference in connotation is *very* minor, and could be disputed.

Comment: ±1- Idiomatic usage presented may not be universal, regional preferences may exist. Recommended action is edit to add that qualification. Otherwise seems very good.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases they are interchangeable. Both constructions are common in large regions and may be understood by many English speakers. Search engines will treat the two as identical.